# Is this the max memory I can reserve for a process?

Tags: c, memory-management

```
char bytes[0x7FFFFFFF]; /* this? */

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Over 2Gb? (if i calc it right)

I'm in a 32bit system, with 4Gb of memory. In a different system that would be more or less?

Comment: Depending on how much contiguous memory you have available, you can allocate more than 0x7FFFFFFF chars (which is not over 2GB, it's just under). And yes, the maximum you can allocate depends on the memory size. If you really need that much memory, your program won't run on a smaller machine. But what do you want to know? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MrLister - I'm trying to do nothing, hehe. I'm just curious. So in a machine with 512Mb my programm won't run? or just crash if i try to access more than 512?

Comment: And then you can encounter things like Linux memory overcommit and "successfully" malloc a 1.4TB block of memory only to be poked with the pointy stick of death, err OOM killer, when you try using it.

Comment: A good compiler will limit your objects to at most half the size of address space (0x7fffffff in your case) because anything larger would result in dangerous overflows (thus undefined behavior) when subtracting pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends by:

- the compiler
- the system
- the OS

If you're running on win32, you are not even using your 4GB or RAM!

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is going to be dependent on a number of factors like platform and even configuration on the platform. The max address space available to a 32-bit process is *typically* restricted by where the user/kernel space split is, which often is either 3G/1G or 2G/2G (user/kernel).

Now, likely creating an array like that won't actually "reserve" all that memory. Rather it would be mapped into the virtual address space and wouldn't actually start consuming memory until it's accessed (see: on demand paging).

Also, remember that you have to share your address space with everything else in your program, including the code. If you consumed all of that with an array, where would your code go?

Comment: It **will** reserve memory, even if it does not physically instantiate it right away. This is called commit charge.